# jQuery DOM Objects and Passing by Reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

First let me preface this question by saying that I'm fairly new to Javascript.

I also understand that Javascript objects are passed by reference and primitives are passed by value [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)].

That said, here's my question (simplified example):  I'm pulling in JSON data that contains a lot of different information and I need to put each different type of information into a `<ul>` that's in another `<ul>` like this:

```
<ul class="car-tree">
  <li>
    <label>Sports Cars</label>
    <ul class="sport-cars">
      <li>Porsche</li>
      <li>Mercedes</li>
      <li>BMW</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Super Cars</label>
    <ul class="super-cars">
      <li>Ferrari</li>
      <li>Lamborghini</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- and so on... -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm grabbing a template for the list above that contains everything except the inner most `<li>` tags and I'm trying to populate it like this:

```
var CarView = function(){

  var buildCarTree = function(){

    // Gets the JSON data from somewhere
    var jsonData = grabJsonData();

    // Grab the template and convert it into a jQuery object
    var template = $(grabCarTreeTemplate());

    // Adds sport car data to sports cars list
    this.addCars(template.find('.sports-cars'), jsonData.sportsCars);

    // Adds super car data to sports cars list
    this.addCars(template.find('.super-cars'), jsonData.superCars);

    // Add the car tree to some container
    $('#container-trees').append(template);
  }

  var addCars = function(container, carData){

    for(id in carData){
      $('<li/>', {
        text : carData[id].text
      }).appendTo(container);
    }
  }
};

var view = new CarView();
view.buildCarTree();
```

When you do this you get the template without the data being added in, although, if you add in `console.log` statements through out `addCars` you can see the data being added to the `container` argument.

I'm confused because from what I understand from the source I provided above:

> ...if you change the parameter itself...that won't affect the item
>   that was  fed into the parameter. But if you change the INTERNALS of
>   the parameter,  that will propagate back up...

and I would have figured that `appendTo` would be changing the internals of the jQuery object.  What's the deal?

Comment: Is `grabJsonData` making an ajax request? If so, you have async issues. Post the contents of `grabJsonData` and I'll show you how to fix.

Comment: No that's not the problem.  The JSON part isn't important because I can see the lists being modified correctly inside addCars, but when I leave that function, the list doesn't reflect those modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call private var functions as if they were methods of the obj. Change to this and try:

```
var CarView = function(){

  this.buildCarTree = function(){

    // Gets the JSON data from somewhere
    var jsonData = grabJsonData();

    // Grab the template and convert it into a jQuery object
    var template = $(grabCarTreeTemplate());

    // Adds sport car data to sports cars list
    this.addCars(template.find('.sports-cars'), jsonData.sportsCars);

    // Adds super car data to sports cars list
    this.addCars(template.find('.super-cars'), jsonData.superCars);

    // Add the car tree to some container
    $('#container-trees').append(template);
  }

  this.addCars = function(container, carData){

    for(id in carData){
      $('<li/>', {
        text : carData[id].text
      }).appendTo(container);
    }
  }
};

var view = new CarView();
view.buildCarTree();
```

**EDIT**: See this jsFiddle for working code: http://jsfiddle.net/eHrH6/

Comment: Correct you are!  Now I feel silly for overlooking that...boy do I miss pair-programming!